# How to load a WFS correctly on QGIS Server?

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-server

I am trying to load a URL for a WFS on my QGIS Server but keep on getting the following error:

```
<ServerException>Project file error. For OWS services: please provide a SERVICE and a MAP parameter pointing to a valid QGIS project file</ServerException>
```

Here is the URL I am using, which includes both service and map parameters:

```
http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WFS&MAP=C:\Users\SSD-LAP-483\Desktop\cesium\BBD_server_test.qgz%20&TYPENAME=Storm_Surge_100_25yrRP_merge_simp3&%20REQUEST=GetFeature&BBOX=13,-59.7,13.4,-59.38
```

When creating a URL for a WMS using the same URL, it works well so I do not think it is an issue with the file path.

Comment: There shouldn't be any spaces (%20) in your connection string

Comment: For a connection to a WFS in QGIS desktop you would want just: `http://localhost:8080/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?MAP=C:\Users\SSD-LAP-483\Desktop\cesium\BBD_server_test.qgz&`